# Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно закодировать строку текста

Tags: c#

Читаю текст из файла в текстбокс. Попробовал преобразовать его в число и работать в дальнейшем с числом, не получилось. Подскажите пожалуйста, как поступить.

```
string[] str = new string[textBox1.Lines.Length];
int[] change = new int[textBox1.Lines.Length];
str[0] = textBox1.Lines[0];
change[0] = Convert.ToInt32(str[0]);
textBox2.Text = str[0];
textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(change[0]);
```

Закодировать требуется многострочный текст, вот фрагмент текста

```
fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Memo2->Clear();
FILE *f1 = 0;
int c1, i = 0;
```

Comment: `Читаю текст из файла в текстбокс. Попробовал преобразовать его в число` текст из файла в число?

Comment: Согласен, изначально глупая идея